# Symfony Doctrine update many to one

Tags: symfony, doctrine, many-to-one

I have two entities:

1)

```
    /**
     * Post
     *
     * @ORM\Table(name="article")
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\PostRepository")
     */
    class Post
    {
        /**
         * @var int
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        private $id;

        ...

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Image", cascade={"persist"}, fetch="EAGER")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="image", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
         */
        private $image;
}
```

and 2)

```
/**
 * Image
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="image")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ImageRepository")
 */
class Image
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="string", length=40)
 * @ORM\Id
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="small", type="blob", nullable=true)
 */
private $small;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="medium", type="blob", nullable=true)
 */
private $medium;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="large", type="blob", nullable=true)
 */
private $large;

...
```

}

Both entities have getters and setters.

The controller sets the post to update

```
$requestFile = $request->files->get('image');
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $record = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Post')->find($id);

    if (!$record) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException(
            'No product found for id '.$record
        );
    }

    $record->setTitle($request->request->get('title'));
    $record->constructAlias($request->request->get('title'));
    ...

    if ($request->files->get('image')) {

        // check if image already exists
        $imgGeneratedId = sha1_file($request->files->get('image')->getPathName());
        $imageRepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Image');
        $isPresent = $imageRepo->find($imgGeneratedId);
        $image = $isPresent;

        if (!$isPresent) {
            $image = new Image();
            $image->setId($imgGeneratedId);
            $image->setLarge(file_get_contents($request->files->get('image')->getPathName()));

            $mediumImage = 
             ...
            $em->persist($image);

        }
     $record->setImage($em->getReference('AppBundle:Image', $image->getId()));
    }

    $em->persist($record);
    $em->flush();
```

Please ignore any syntax errors or other kinds; there are none.

The problem is that even if image already exists it is trying to create one which causes error in database. So, in order to avoid this I used **getReference**, but this causes other issues.

So, how can I force doctrine, not to insert an image if already exists and just set the article image with the image id?

Thanks.

Comment: So `$isPresent` is `NULL`?

Comment: If null I create an Image to be save